# How to get content of ExtensionData

Tags: c#, wcf

Adding `IExtensibleDataObject` to `DataContract` class in WCF allow storage of "unknown" contract members.

Using reflection, I can access the `Members` property of `ExtensionData`. And I guess that using more reflection I will finally have access to the `Name` and `Value` of each member.

Is there any other way to achieve such goal?

Comment: How about `dynamic`? (Which would be under the hood also nothing more than Reflection.)

Comment: I should have add using C# 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question: No.